# AdobeAssetFile: can't tracking upload progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, adobecreativesdk

I'm trying to upload image to Adobe Creative Cloud using method `create:folder:dataPath:contentType:progressBlock:successBlock:cancellationBlock:errorBlock` of AdobeAssetFile. File upload succesfully, but I can't track upload progress with `progressBlock`. This block just don't invocated.

```
- (void)sendImageWithURL:(NSURL *)imageURL {
    NSString *imageName = [imageURL lastPathComponent];    
    [AdobeAssetFile create:imageName
                    folder:[AdobeAssetFolder root]
                  dataPath:imageURL
               contentType:[AdobeAssetMimeTypes mimeTypeForExtension:@"jpg"]
           collisionPolicy:AdobeAssetFileCollisionPolicyAppendUniqueNumber
             progressBlock:^(double fractionCompleted) {
                 NSLog(@"Progress: %f", fractionCompleted);
             }
              successBlock:^(AdobeAssetFile *file) {
                  NSLog(@"Operation is complete");
              }
         cancellationBlock:^{
             NSLog(@"Operation is canceled");
         }
                errorBlock:^(NSError *error){
                    NSLog(@"Error is occur: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                }
     ];
}
```

What's wrong with this code? And why `progressBlock` not invocated?

I'm using Adobe Creative SDK v0.13.2139.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. This is a known issue. A fix is in the works.